# jQuery Swap image based on lang

Tags: jquery, if-statement, lang

Trying to swap the home button image based on the lang element. So far no luck.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('html').attr('lang') == 'fr' ) {
    $('#imgLogo').attr('src', 'path/to/file.jpg');
  } else {}
});
```

Stumped.

Comment: Were exactly are you picking the language attribute from.  can you please update your question.

Comment: you could use console.log() javascript function in firefox (with firebug) to find out what does $('html').attr('lang') returns

Comment: Do you have access to server code? is better to control that condition server side.

Comment: No access to server coder.

Comment: 'lang' returns either 'fr' or 'en'. Trying to switch the image dependent upon the language defaulted by the CMS.

Comment: The 'lang' attribute is determined by the CMS, according to a user's selected language option (Canadian French/English users).

Comment: Maybe I'm going about this wrong. Thanks for the suggestion, Simon. Firebug console returns 'undefined', but lang is an element in the body... Clearly a noob.

Comment: Aha! So switched 'html' to 'body' and it gave me 'en'! Awesome.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring out it was the 'html' tag. The console.log() led me to it. Thanks, Simon Paquet.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('body').attr('lang') == 'fr' ) {
    $('#imgLogo').attr('src', 'path/to/file.jpg');
  } else {}
});
```